# Twitter-Bootstrap shall I start a new row after each 12 columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is this OK?

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <h1>A header</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <p>A text....</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

It works, but should I start a new row when I have used 12 columns?

Comment: On this case no. But it s my opinion.

Comment: **From Bootstrap docs:** Grid columns are created by specifying the number of twelve available columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use three .col-xs-4. If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

Comment: As @makshh notes, Bootstrap's documentation does not REQUIRE a new `.row` for every 12-column combination.  Any recommendation for or against doing so seems primarily opinion-based which makes this not the sort of question usually answerable on SO.